# Apache Camel Cxf OneWay method not handle SoapFault

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, soapfault, oneway

I have a very simple camel route that makes soap to soap calls.

Everything work fine, but if one of the @Oneway operation throws SaopFault, I cannot catch the fault onException. How can I catch soapFault onException to set message to setBody(soapFault)?

Thank you for your help.

**This method throws SaopFault from targetService**

```
  @WebMethod(operationName = "OneWayOperation")
  @Oneway
  public void onewayOperation(
        @WebParam(partName = "OneWayOperationRequest", 
                  name = "OneWayOperationRequest", 
                  targetNamespace = "http://xxx.xxx.com/xmlschema/api")
        com.xxx.xxx.xmlschema.api.OneWayOperationRequest oneWayOperationRequest
    );
```

```
    @Bean(name = "sourceBean")
    public CxfEndpoint buildCxfSoapEndpoint() {
        CxfEndpoint cxf = new CxfEndpoint();
        cxf.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:9090/api");
        cxf.setServiceClass(com.xxx.Service.class);
        cxf.setWsdlURL("wsdl/xxx.wsdl");
        return cxf;
    }

    @Bean(name = "targetBean")
    public CxfEndpoint buildCxfSoapEndpoint() {
        CxfEndpoint cxf = new CxfEndpoint();
        cxf.setAddress("https://xxxx.com:443/api");
        cxf.setServiceClass(com.xxx.Service.class);
        cxf.setWsdlURL("wsdl/xxx.wsdl");
        return cxf;
    }

        from("cxf:bean:sourceBean")
                .to("cxf:bean:targetBean")
                .onException(SoapFault.class)
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        SoapFault fault = exchange.getProperty(ExchangePropertyKey.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, SoapFault.class);
                       // **  OneWay methods never comes here but the others ! **
                    }
                })
```

Comment: I have removed the   @Oneway annotation from generated clasess for workaround solution and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added ?dataFormat=MESSAGE and problem solved.

```
from("cxf:bean:sourceBean?dataFormat=MESSAGE")
            .to("cxf:bean:targetBean?dataFormat=MESSAGE")
```